# Adding google authenticator and use only email address of user

Tags: plugins, login, google

I think most of you have seen SO way of authenticating. SO uses only ask for email address through Google Authentication.

Can this feature be applied to a wordpress site.. like allowing users to give only their email and no password since the user will only have the ability to view the content, we dont't need users to provide passwords, so just email is sufficient for identity..

Is their any plugin to achieve this?

If not a little help with StackExchange team how do they implement that signup from google resources..

Comment: Perhaphs this [Google Authentication Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-apps-login/) is what you're after?

Comment: well how does it work? If possible please make it in answer..